# Using 2 API components with 2 stages AWS Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an api server running with AWS Api Gateway

The api gateway contains two stages - 'prod' and 'test'

let's say my url is `google.com`, containing "home" page:

- in 'test' stage it will be - google.com/test/home
- in 'prod' stage it will be - google.com/prod/home

In aws it redirects to the same component.
But I have two different codes for home dir in test and in prod stages.

How can I make aws api access one url for one stage and another one for another stage, containing the same url dir as shown? (both containing the "/xxxx/home" dir, each in it's own stage)

Answer (score 0):

Application Load Balancer with path-base routing can be used to achieve this. [Details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html).